# Accessing the values of base classifiers from stacked ensemble model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How can I access the values of the base classifiers from a stacked ensemble mode? I used StackingClassifier from sklearn.

When I implement this:

`model.final_estimator_.decision_function(X_train)`

I got this error:

`X has 10 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 4 features as input.`

I have a stacked ensemble model with:

- Decision tree, linear regression, XGB and MLP as base classifer
- Linear regression as meta classifier

Im just curious how could I access what is passed from the base classifier to the metaclassifier

Answer (score 0):

The fitted base estimators are stored in the attribute `estimators_` and `named_estimators_`, so you can inspect them directly that way.  The ensemble's `transform` method returns an array with columns being the base estimators' predictions, so that's a more convenient way to "access what is passed from the base classifier to the metaclassifier".  (And of course the ensemble's `predict` method(s) will make the base estimators' predictions as in `transform` and then use that as input to the `final_estimator_.predict`.)

Comment: I could return the base ensemble names using `named_estimators_` which shows Decision tree, linear regression, XGB and MLP being fitted. How could I access the `transform` method as it is I couldn't find it in the documentation and it returns an error for it.

Comment: `model.transform`?  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.transform